# Nuevamente no puedo preguntar

Tags: discusión, soporte

Hace unas semanas no podía preguntar porque tenia puntaje negativo, nunca aceptaba las respuestas entre otras cosas, luego, hace unos días volví a poder preguntar, ya que acepte preguntas, puntué etc.

Ahora voy a preguntar y resulta que otra vez no puedo preguntar, y nadie me puntuó negativo ni nada que se le parezca, alguien me puede decir que pasó?

Comment: No sé el motivo de tu problema, pero me pregunto ¿Has ayudado en la cola de revisión? ¿Has editado para mejorar otras publicaciones?, etc, quizas eso te ayude para ganar algun puntaje asi el sistema te permita hacer nuevas preguntas.

Comment: @eyllanesc todo esto ayuda a la comunidad, faltaría más, pero no contribuye en nada al levantamiento del veto a preguntar: este se basa únicamente en las preguntas que tenga cada uno. Por tanto, toca editarlas, mejorarlas, conseguir votos o reaperturas.

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, no conozco las reglas de como el sistema evalua si un usuario puede tener el privilegio de preguntar, pero revisando el puntaje de las preguntas, las respuestas marcadas como correcta, etc: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27283/cribelo?tab=questions&sort=newest veo que son los valores de un usuario promedio, es decir, algunas preguntas sin respuestas seleccionadas, otras sí, algunas sin respuestas, 1 puesta en espera, ninguna con voto negativo, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc seguramente tenga preguntas borradas

Comment: @fedorqui ¿En donde puedo encontrar los criterior que tiene el sistema para habilitar/deshabilitar el privilegio de preguntar de un usuario?

Comment: Claro, el tema es que hace creo 4 dias que pude volver a preguntar, y en esos 4 dias solo hice una pregunta , la cual acepté una respuesta, y nada mas, no entiendo por que ahora no puedo preguntar, la verdad que las políticas son muy ambiguas.Un ejemplo:
Hice una pregunta hace unos dias, un usuario me respondió y otro usuario lo punto negativo a ese porque supuestamente estaba mal la respuesta, y a mi me había servido mucho, es mas, la puse como respuesta, el problema que veo es que quizá alguien te puntúa negativo y otro positivo por la misma respuesta, es según el punto de vista...

Comment: @Cribelo las respuestas son independientes de la pregunta en el caso de puntaje

Comment: @eyl mira los comentarios a la anterior pregunta de este AP. Es que estoy con el móvil y no tengo los enlaces a mano. Comentario mío sobre Meta.SE y el de Pikoh.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias, ya encontre el enlace. Aun sin leer el post de META.SE que señalas tengo una duda, entiendo que si el OP pudo realizar una pregunta, despues del bloqueo anterior, entonces al menos para el sistema el paso  el umbral necesario, entiendo que si desde ese momento hasta ahora solo tuvo preguntas con puntaje positivo deberia mantener el mismo privilegio. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @eyl podría ser que hubiera tenido votos negativos en publicaciones antiguas (si bien el efecto Meta en este caso ha obrado en sentido favorable al AP, con multitud de votos positivos, según veo en su perfil). Sin saber si hay otras preguntas borradas, es difícil saber. La fórmula exacta creo que no está disponible, pero parece que está en el límite y a veces cae arriba y a veces abajo.

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo ello, pero parece que es una confusión como señala gbianchi ya que si se revisa la reputación del OP: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27283/cribelo?tab=reputation no se ve downvotes

Comment: @eyllanesc supongo que es algo que cambió durante el transcurso del rato desde que publicó la pregunta y recibió votos positivos. Pero todo son especulaciones, supongo que los moderadores podrán ver algo más de información en el historial "secreto".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No estas bloqueado para preguntar en este momento. Pero tene en cuenta lo siguiente, tu ultima pregunta nuevamente estuvo mal, ya que fue hecha en meta y no en el sitio principal.

Nada tienen que ver los puntos sobre las respuestas a tu bloqueo para preguntar.

Tu ultima pregunta, nuevamente sufre problemas de forma. Es amplisima, no demuestra investigacion de ningun tipo de tu parte, y la respuesta, aunque correcta, no esta completa ni mucho menos.

Si tu proxima pregunta no es buena, el sistema va a volver a bloquearte. Y cada bloqueo va a ser peor que el anterior.